# Does Windows have a "this core may ONLY run this program and should otherwise be idle" setting?

Tags: windows, cpu, core

Someone in The Bridge, the main chatroom for Arqade, our gaming site, asked whether they can fully dedicate a CPU core to a specific program, to the point that if that program isn't active, the core isn't either.

https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50945749#50945749

> Also, I am not sure how Windows do its threading. I am unsure if there is a setup or configuration to do something like "Nothing else uses this core except X"

I know about Process Affinity and how it can force a program to only use 1 specific core, but I don't know if the reverse, forcing a core to only work on one specific program, is possible. Does Windows have an option for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does Windows have an option for this?

Windows doesn’t have a feature like that.  In order to disable a specific core through **msconfig** it would require a reboot.

However, any cores you disabled would not be available to any program at that point.